# Readline printing just characters

Tags: python

I run this code in the Python IDLE, and it will only return the amount of letters specified instead of the line specified.

```
 if os.path.exists(saveDir + name + '.txt') == True:
    print('welcome back ' + name + '.')

    file = open(saveDir + name + '.txt')
    race = file.readline(1)
else:
    race = intro()
```

When I print the race variable, it comes out as the G (The input name is Grant).
The text file looks like this

```
Grant
Human
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`race = file.readline(1)` returns 1 byte (character) of the line (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html?highlight=readline#io.IOBase.readline)). You want to return the entire line so call `race = file.readline()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read a single line, or all the lines? `file.readline()` will return the first line of the file as a string. If called again, it will return the second line, and so on. You can also load all the lines of the file as a list with `file.readlines()`, and then get the first or second element by using `[0]` or `[1]`, so `file.readlines()[1]` will yield "Human".

Answer (score 0):

```
 if os.path.exists(saveDir + name + '.txt') == True:
    print('welcome back ' + name + '.')

    file = open(saveDir + name + '.txt')
    race = file.readline() # this reads one line at a time
    raceType = file.readline() # this will give you the second line (human)
else:
    race = intro()
```